# bashrc script outputs non-printing character

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I added this bash script to my ./bashrc but a non-printing character appears in my terminal when the script runs, how can I fix it ?

```
    #!/bin/sh

##  +-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
##  |                                                                       |
##  |                            FANCY BASH PROMT                           |
##  |                                                                       |
##  | Copyright (c) 2018, Andres Gongora <mail@andresgongora.com>.          |
##  |                                                                       |
##  | This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify  |
##  | it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  |
##  | the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or     |
##  | (at your option) any later version.                                   |
##  |                                                                       |
##  | This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,       |
##  | but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of        |
##  | MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the         |
##  | GNU General Public License for more details.                          |
##  |                                                                       |
##  | You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License     |
##  | along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  |
##  |                                                                       |
##  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+


##
##  DESCRIPTION:
##  This script updates your "PS1" environment variable to display colors.
##  Addicitionally, it also shortens the name of your current part to maximum
##  25 characters, which is quite useful when working in deeply nested folders.
##
##
##
##  INSTALLATION:
##  Copy this script to your home folder and rename it to ".fancy-bash-promt.sh"
##  Run this command from any terminal: 
##      echo "source ~/.fancy-bash-promt.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
##
##  Alternatively, copy the content of this file into your .bashrc file
##
##
##
##  FUNCTIONS:
##
##  * bash_prompt_command()
##    This function takes your current working directory and stores a shortened
##    version in the variable "NEW_PWD".
##
##  * format_font()
##    A small helper function to generate color formating codes from simple
##    number codes (defined below as local variables for convenience).
##
##  * bash_prompt()
##    This function colorizes the bash promt. The exact color scheme can be
##    configured here. The structure of the function is as follows:
##      1. A. Definition of available colors for 16 bits.
##      1. B. Definition of some colors for 256 bits (add your own).
##      2. Configuration >> EDIT YOUR PROMT HERE<<.
##      4. Generation of color codes.
##      5. Generation of window title (some terminal expect the first
##         part of $PS1 to be the window title)
##      6. Formating of the bash promt ($PS1).
##
##  * Main script body: 
##    It calls the adequate helper functions to colorize your promt and sets
##    a hook to regenerate your working directory "NEW_PWD" when you change it.
## 




################################################################################
##  FUNCTIONS                                                                 ##
################################################################################

##
##  ARRANGE $PWD AND STORE IT IN $NEW_PWD
##  * The home directory (HOME) is replaced with a ~
##  * The last pwdmaxlen characters of the PWD are displayed
##  * Leading partial directory names are striped off
##      /home/me/stuff -> ~/stuff (if USER=me)
##      /usr/share/big_dir_name -> ../share/big_dir_name (if pwdmaxlen=20)
##
##  Original source: WOLFMAN'S color bash promt
##  https://wiki.chakralinux.org/index.php?title=Color_Bash_Prompt#Wolfman.27s
##
bash_prompt_command() {
    # How many characters of the $PWD should be kept
    local pwdmaxlen=25

    # Indicate that there has been dir truncation
    local trunc_symbol=".."

    # Store local dir
    local dir=${PWD##*/}

    # Which length to use
    pwdmaxlen=$(( ( pwdmaxlen < ${#dir} ) ? ${#dir} : pwdmaxlen ))

    NEW_PWD=${PWD/#$HOME/\~}

    local pwdoffset=$(( ${#NEW_PWD} - pwdmaxlen ))

    # Generate name
    if [ ${pwdoffset} -gt "0" ]
    then
        NEW_PWD=${NEW_PWD:$pwdoffset:$pwdmaxlen}
        NEW_PWD=${trunc_symbol}/${NEW_PWD#*/}
    fi
}




##
##  GENERATE A FORMAT SEQUENCE
##
format_font()
{
    ## FIRST ARGUMENT TO RETURN FORMAT STRING
    local output=$1


    case $# in
    2)
        eval $output="'\[\033[0;${2}m\]'"
        ;;
    3)
        eval $output="'\[\033[0;${2};${3}m\]'"
        ;;
    4)
        eval $output="'\[\033[0;${2};${3};${4}m\]'"
        ;;
    *)
        eval $output="'\[\033[0m\]'"
        ;;
    esac
}



##
## COLORIZE BASH PROMT
##
bash_prompt() {

    ############################################################################
    ## COLOR CODES                                                            ##
    ## These can be used in the configuration below                           ##
    ############################################################################

    ## FONT EFFECT
    local      NONE='0'
    local      BOLD='1'
    local       DIM='2'
    local UNDERLINE='4'
    local     BLINK='5'
    local    INVERT='7'
    local    HIDDEN='8'


    ## COLORS
    local   DEFAULT='9'
    local     BLACK='0'
    local       RED='1'
    local     GREEN='2'
    local    YELLOW='3'
    local      BLUE='4'
    local   MAGENTA='5'
    local      CYAN='7'
    local    L_GRAY='7'
    local    D_GRAY='60'
    local     L_RED='61'
    local   L_GREEN='62'
    local  L_YELLOW='63'
    local    L_BLUE='64'
    local L_MAGENTA='65'
    local    L_CYAN='66'
    local     WHITE='67'


    ## TYPE
    local     RESET='0'
    local    EFFECT='0'
    local     COLOR='30'
    local        BG='40'


    ## 256 COLOR CODES
    local NO_FORMAT="\[\033[0m\]"
    local ORANGE_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;208m\]"
    local TOXIC_GREEN_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;118m\]"
    local RED_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;1m\]"
    local CYAN_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;87m\]"
    local BLACK_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;0m\]"
    local WHITE_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;15m\]"
    local GRAY_BOLD="\[\033[1;90m\]"
    local BLUE_BOLD="\[\033[1;38;5;74m\]"





    ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  
      ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
    ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ## 



    ##                          CONFIGURE HERE                                ##



    ############################################################################
    ## CONFIGURATION                                                          ##
    ## Choose your color combination here                                     ##
    ############################################################################
    local FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE
    local BACKGROUND_1=$BLUE
    local TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD

    local FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE
    local BACKGROUND_2=$L_BLUE
    local TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD

    local FONT_COLOR_3=$D_GRAY
    local BACKGROUND_3=$WHITE
    local TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD

    local PROMT_FORMAT=$BLUE_BOLD


    ############################################################################
    ## EXAMPLE CONFIGURATIONS                                                 ##
    ## I use them for different hosts. Test them out ;)                       ##
    ############################################################################

    ## CONFIGURATION: BLUE-WHITE
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = dell ]; then
        FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_1=$BLUE; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$L_BLUE; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD   
        FONT_COLOR_3=$D_GRAY; BACKGROUND_3=$WHITE; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD   
        PROMT_FORMAT=$CYAN_BOLD
    fi

    ## CONFIGURATION: BLACK-RED
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = giraff6 ]; then
        FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_1=$BLACK; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$D_GRAY; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_3=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_3=$RED; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD
        PROMT_FORMAT=$RED_BOLD
    fi

    ## CONFIGURATION: RED-BLACK
    #FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_1=$RED; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
    #FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$D_GRAY; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD
    #FONT_COLOR_3=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_3=$BLACK; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD
    #PROMT_FORMAT=$RED_BOLD

    ## CONFIGURATION: CYAN-BLUE
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = sharkoon ]; then
        FONT_COLOR_1=$BLACK; BACKGROUND_1=$L_CYAN; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$L_BLUE; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_3=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_3=$BLUE; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD
        PROMT_FORMAT=$CYAN_BOLD
    fi

    ## CONFIGURATION: GRAY-SCALE
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = giraff ]; then
        FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_1=$BLACK; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$D_GRAY; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_3=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_3=$L_GRAY; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD
        PROMT_FORMAT=$BLACK_BOLD
    fi

    ## CONFIGURATION: GRAY-CYAN
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = light ]; then
        FONT_COLOR_1=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_1=$BLACK; TEXTEFFECT_1=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_2=$WHITE; BACKGROUND_2=$D_GRAY; TEXTEFFECT_2=$BOLD
        FONT_COLOR_3=$BLACK; BACKGROUND_3=$L_CYAN; TEXTEFFECT_3=$BOLD
        PROMT_FORMAT=$CYAN_BOLD
    fi


    ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  
      ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
    ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  




    ############################################################################
    ## TEXT FORMATING                                                         ##
    ## Generate the text formating according to configuration                 ##
    ############################################################################

    ## CONVERT CODES: add offset
    FC1=$(($FONT_COLOR_1+$COLOR))
    BG1=$(($BACKGROUND_1+$BG))
    FE1=$(($TEXTEFFECT_1+$EFFECT))

    FC2=$(($FONT_COLOR_2+$COLOR))
    BG2=$(($BACKGROUND_2+$BG))
    FE2=$(($TEXTEFFECT_2+$EFFECT))

    FC3=$(($FONT_COLOR_3+$COLOR))
    BG3=$(($BACKGROUND_3+$BG))
    FE3=$(($TEXTEFFECT_3+$EFFECT))

    FC4=$(($FONT_COLOR_4+$COLOR))
    BG4=$(($BACKGROUND_4+$BG))
    FE4=$(($TEXTEFFECT_4+$EFFECT))


    ## CALL FORMATING HELPER FUNCTION: effect + font color + BG color
    local TEXT_FORMAT_1
    local TEXT_FORMAT_2
    local TEXT_FORMAT_3
    local TEXT_FORMAT_4 
    format_font TEXT_FORMAT_1 $FE1 $FC1 $BG1
    format_font TEXT_FORMAT_2 $FE2 $FC2 $BG2
    format_font TEXT_FORMAT_3 $FC3 $FE3 $BG3
    format_font TEXT_FORMAT_4 $FC4 $FE4 $BG4


    # GENERATE PROMT SECTIONS
    local PROMT_USER=$"$TEXT_FORMAT_1 \u "
    local PROMT_HOST=$"$TEXT_FORMAT_2 \h "
    local PROMT_PWD=$"$TEXT_FORMAT_3 \${NEW_PWD} "
    local PROMT_INPUT=$"$PROMT_FORMAT "


    ############################################################################
    ## SEPARATOR FORMATING                                                    ##
    ## Generate the separators between sections                               ##
    ## Uses background colors of the sections                                 ##
    ############################################################################

    ## CONVERT CODES
    TSFC1=$(($BACKGROUND_1+$COLOR))
    TSBG1=$(($BACKGROUND_2+$BG))

    TSFC2=$(($BACKGROUND_2+$COLOR))
    TSBG2=$(($BACKGROUND_3+$BG))

    TSFC3=$(($BACKGROUND_3+$COLOR))
    TSBG3=$(($DEFAULT+$BG))


    ## CALL FORMATING HELPER FUNCTION: effect + font color + BG color
    local SEPARATOR_FORMAT_1
    local SEPARATOR_FORMAT_2
    local SEPARATOR_FORMAT_3
    format_font SEPARATOR_FORMAT_1 $TSFC1 $TSBG1
    format_font SEPARATOR_FORMAT_2 $TSFC2 $TSBG2
    format_font SEPARATOR_FORMAT_3 $TSFC3 $TSBG3


    # GENERATE SEPARATORS WITH FANCY TRIANGLE
    local TRIANGLE=$'\uE0B0'    
    local SEPARATOR_1=$SEPARATOR_FORMAT_1$TRIANGLE
    local SEPARATOR_2=$SEPARATOR_FORMAT_2$TRIANGLE
    local SEPARATOR_3=$SEPARATOR_FORMAT_3$TRIANGLE



    ############################################################################
    ## WINDOW TITLE                                                           ##
    ## Prevent messed up terminal-window titles                               ##
    ############################################################################
    case $TERM in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        local TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u:${NEW_PWD}\007\]'
        ;;
    *)
        local TITLEBAR=""
        ;;
    esac



    ############################################################################
    ## BASH PROMT                                                             ##
    ## Generate promt and remove format from the rest                         ##
    ############################################################################
    PS1="$TITLEBAR\n${PROMT_USER}${SEPARATOR_1}${PROMT_HOST}${SEPARATOR_2}${PROMT_PWD}${SEPARATOR_3}${PROMT_INPUT}"



    ## For terminal line coloring, leaving the rest standard
    none="$(tput sgr0)"
    trap 'echo -ne "${none}"' DEBUG
}




################################################################################
##  MAIN                                                                      ##
################################################################################

##  Bash provides an environment variable called PROMPT_COMMAND. 
##  The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command 
##  just before Bash displays a prompt. 
##  We want it to call our own command to truncate PWD and store it in NEW_PWD
PROMPT_COMMAND=bash_prompt_command

##  Call bash_promnt only once, then unset it (not needed any more)
##  It will set $PS1 with colors and relative to $NEW_PWD, 
##  which gets updated by $PROMT_COMMAND on behalf of the terminal
bash_prompt
unset bash_prompt



### EOF ###
```

but my terminal output is following

```
[akkilah  akkilah-PC  ~ ]
```

how to remove these non-printing  characters?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SEZV.png) here a picture of my command line

update 1 : I find this maybe intersting :

```
akkilah  akkilah-PC  ~  echo "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"
\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699
```

update 2 :

```
akkilah  akkilah-PC  ~  echo -e "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"
 ±  ➦ ✘ ⚡ ⚙
```

Comment: change font, some font does not have the 'triangle' on \ue0b0.

Comment: same issue nothing change ..

Comment: do echo -e "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"

Comment: i use konsole Terminus(TTF)

Comment: this is the result : 
akkilah  akkilah-PC  ~  echo -e "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"
 ±  ➦ ✘ ⚡ ⚙

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its printing what it is meant to print. You just need some font to render the icons.

I would suggest fira-code fonts. 
try this and check prompt.

```
sudo apt install fonts-firacode
```

Comment: its worked after i  install fonts-firacode , but i didn't use this font. what did just happen ?

Comment: you are using non printing character for showing special symbols.. and *I guess* if one font cannot render those, it falls back on other. thats why its working now