# What packages do I need to run these graphics in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

Running Ubuntu 18.04.5.

I am trying to get the following bash terminal look
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM9aB.png).

But when I add the github code to my .bashrc file, I get the following:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU5Ma.png)

Do you know what packages I need to install, or what i'm missing that prevents me from getting the desired look?

Comment: Who said you need to install packages?

Comment: I just assumed that i am missing some software that is causing the commands i added to .bashrc not to be rendered properly

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you shared what "the github code" is, exactly

Comment: think you need the [fonts-firacode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229524/bashrc-script-outputs-non-printing-character/1229573#1229573) package or [fonts-powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)